# Passing variables between GLSLES vertex & fragment shaders

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glsl, shader, glsles

Whenever I look at sample shaders, it seems this type of stuff happens almost by magic; sometimes information is saved into special places like position/color, but other times a fragment shader uses parameters and quite how fragment shader knows where to get this data I can't follow.

Can anyone provide a medium-simple GLES shader which does this, and explain how it works?

Comment: Why would anyone bother voting to close a question, especially as "not a proper question", when *it's already been marked as answered*?!

Comment: Just because someone guessed your answer doesn't make it a real question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [OpenGL ES quick reference card](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf).

You're interested in the "**Built-In Inputs, Outputs, and Constants**" later where GLSL is described, in particular vertex shader outputs and fragment shader inputs.

Additional VS outputs (that become FS inputs) should be declared in both using the `varying` keyword.

Comment: So simply by declaring them, that's the 'magic' part where they get glued together automatically? Does a `varying` appear only to the linked fragment shader, or is it floating around for anything to see?

Comment: When you `LinkProgram`, the linker will look at varying vars in the attached VS and PS. You'll get a linker error if they don't match.